# Codeigniter :: how to add a form based on multiple data input when editing the data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table whose contents based id_product, when I edit the automatic reference is the id_product, and there are data from multiple should I pull and I give them one data of the field how to put the data from multiple database to form input type file and form input type dropdown (SELECTED).

my table color :

```html
+--------------------------------------+
| id_color | id_product | option_color |
----------------------------------------
|    1     |     20     |    white     |
|    2     |     20     |    black     |
+--------------------------------------+

results should be like this :

<select type="select" name="color[]">
  <option value="">blue</option>
  <option value="" selected="selected">white</option>
  <option value="">black</option>
</select>

<select type="select" name="color[]">
  <option value="">blue</option>
  <option value="">white</option>
  <option value="" selected="selected">black</option>
</select>
```

my table image :

```html
+--------------------------------------+
| id_image | id_product |    image     |
----------------------------------------
|    32     |     20     |  pro1.jpg   |
|    33     |     20     |  bl23.jpg   |
+--------------------------------------+

results should be like this :

<input type="file" name="additional_image[]" value="pro1.jpg">
<input type="file" name="additional_image[]" value="bl23.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?

$colors = array(
    0 => 'blue',
    1 => 'white',       
    2=> 'black' 
    );


$products = array(
    array(
        'id_color' => 1,
        'id_product' => 20,
        'option_color' => 'white',
        ),  
    array(
        'id_color' => 2,
        'id_product' => 20,
        'option_color' => 'black',
        ),

);

foreach ($products as $pro) { ?>
    <select type="select" name="color[]"><?
    foreach ($colors as $cid =>$color) { ?>
        <option value="" <? echo $pro['id_color']==$cid?'selected="selected"':'';?> ><? echo $color; ?></option>
    <? }
    ?></select>
<? } ?>
```